# SharePoint 2013: remove orphan site entry from database

Tags: site-collection, restore, orphan

We were moving some sites onto new database,  one of the site restoration interrupted and resulted in having one orphan entry in the database.

We are not able to restore the site backup with the same link,  do we have any option of removing orphan site collection from SharePoint 2013 database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are couple of options you can try to remove the orphan in the databases. Did you try to run the restore with force parameter?

1. Detach the content DB wait for couple of min and re attach it
2. try to repair the Content DB
3. if you have site id (returning while running get-spsite) then you can forcefully delete it from SharePoint via powershell or stsadm
4. you can also try to remove it from database using the powershell.
5. if none working then you have to move all site collection from corrupted DB to new, Once moved then delete the orphan DB.

i already write down the steps here
[Link# 1](http://wscheema.com/blog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=02e7c960-f007-4d7a-8bcf-94ec865f370e&ID=20&Source=http://wscheema.com/blog/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x0110000CE6E96CD858F0419111D3D9045E5621)
[Link#  2](http://wscheema.com/blog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=02e7c960-f007-4d7a-8bcf-94ec865f370e&ID=31&Source=http://wscheema.com/blog/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x0110000CE6E96CD858F0419111D3D9045E5621)

Comment: Waqas,  thanks for this,  I am able to see the site entry when i do a Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase command,  the site is also visible in the Site Map table of config database. I am hopping that re-attaching the db will not have same impact

Comment: then i believe, your best bet is run the stsadm to forcefully delete it...stsadm -o deletesite -force -siteid e2a114b8-80c9-41f6-87bf-3feddf2ad9b6 -databaseserver DS1 -databasename DB1

Comment: Thanks Waqas,  I re-attached the database and orphan entry was removed.  Thanks for your help.